# Quando a textbox for nula, o botão ficará desligado

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando escrever na `textbox`, o botão irá ligar, mas quando não tiver nada na `textbox` vai desligar. Consegui fazer o método do botão ligar porém não consegui fazer o de desligar se a `textbox` for nula

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt.Text == null)
    {
        bt.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        bt.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai depender do comportamento ideal e esperado para isso, ***um exemplo***, se não quiser nem **espaço** em branco vai ter que usar [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx), **exemplo**:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text));
}
```

isso faz com que se colocar espaço sem nenhuma letra, não vai considerar e o botão continua desabilitado, agora se quiser considerar também os espaços para habilitar o botão é só usar propriedade [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) da `classe` [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text.Length > 0;
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Propriedade String.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Classe String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Essa lógica não funciona porque quando a `TextBox` está vazia ela tem a propriedade `Text` como string vazia (`""`) e não `null`.

Logo basta alterar ligeiramente a sua logica:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt.Text == "") //agora com "" de string vazia
    {
        bt.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        bt.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Na verdade pode até compactar bastante esta logica fazendo assim:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bt.Enabled = txt.Text != "";
}
```

Repare que nesta ultima versão o `Enabled` recebe o valor da comparação `txt.Text != ""` e por isso será diretamente o `true` ou `false` que pretende.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando a resposta do Isac, talvez seja interessante adicionar o método `Trim()` ao final, se você não quiser que o botão seja habilitado apenas com a tecla espaço do teclado:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bt.Enabled = txt.Text.Trim() != "";
}
```